kubernetes nginx ingress not responding when server_name is set for host
we have new kubernetes cluster for development on Azure and I installed nginx ingress controller (it worked very well in other places so why not).
But this time it doesn't work as expected. There are no error logs in nginx pods, everything looks good, except when I try to access it with domain name it times out. It works if I try to access same curl command from inside another app pod inside same cluster. And it response Ok if I remove host from ingress (so it's just default server).
I also tried to port-forward to nginx-ingress pod from laptop and curl with host header and localhost ip adress worked.
Ingress definition looks like this:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: backend-ingress
  namespace: dev
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: 'backend.domain.dev'
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: backend-service
              port:
                number: 80

backend.domain.dev ip address points to same address as external ip in nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller. And it have LoadBalancer as type.
Everything works if use just IP external ip address (and don't have host in ingress), bus when I put host (as in example), it works internally but not from outside.
Could someone give ideas, where to dig?
I also tried with port-forward to ingress-nginx pod and curl with host header and localhost ip address worked just find.

It seems like the issue is related to DNS resolution or external access particularly when using the host name. Firstly, verify the DNS for backend.domain.dev is correctly pointing to the external IP address of the NGINX ingress controller’s load balancer and next make sure the host specified in the ingress rule exactly matches the domain you are using and also check your Ingress resource configuration thoroughly.

And check if any firewall rules in Azure that might be blocking traffic to LB and ensure that ports 80 and 440 are open. Refer to this documentation.Additionally you can also look at this for similar kinds of issues.

Did you have time to check my answer? I am looking forward to your response to understand whether the provided information has helped you in resolving the issue. If not, I am happy to assist further.

I double checked and domain name is pointing right and there are no firewall rules blocking. It actually worked when I manually edited nginx.conf inside controller to move default server "_" definition after my server name and returning 200 for everything. Then my service started to work domain name and returning correct data.

nginx version: nginx/1.25.5

Thanks for your reply. Could you please confirm if the issue is fixed?

it is not fixed, if I manually edit nginx.conf file to remove listening for default server, it works. But that is just temporary solution, because as soon as someone edits ingress or adds new one, it will be overwritten. Or if ingress-nginx pod will be killled and new startet, config file will fresh and everything stops working.

While directly editing Nginx.conf is not recommended for production, you can adjust Nginx’s behavior via ConfigMaps. This allows configuration through ConfigMap which is a better approach than directly modifying nginx.config. Refer to these Nginx docs on ConfigMap resources for more details.

I tried, but it seems that it works when I comment listen ports for default backend and move definition after other virtual server. And that sounds very weird that I never experienced, so I wander if it's something to do with latest version og ngninx. It just doesn't make sense for me, that it will start work after moving server definition after other servers.

Different versions of nginx can have variations in behavior. And also in NGINX if multiple server blocks are defined for the same port( Eg: listen 80) , Nginx uses the first server block that matches the request. If you have a server block defined with default_server it will handle all unmatched requests. Additionally you can check this for similar kinds of issues.
